# Viewpager in support library V13

Tags: android, android-support-library, versions

My application uses the ViewPager component extensively, but I've been using Support Library V4 from the beginning and wasn't even aware of the different versions of the library.

I will ask for Android ICS as minimum version to run my app, so change to V13 won't be an issue. However I have a hundred files to change, and I wonder if it's gonna be worth. Besides, I've read here in some questions problems related to Classes not found after the change, and the solution seems to be to include both libraries.

Can anybody please tell me if ViewPager in V13 behaves better in real life? V13 release notes lists a lot of tiny improvements, but to be honest I've never had any problem with the component.

Also, do you know if the bugfixes on V13 are applied retroactively to V4?

Thanks in advance.